# Check subclass of an object in Java

Tags: java, class, subclass, instanceof

Consider the classes `MinorClassA` and `MinorClassB`, both extending `MajorClass`. I have an object of `MajorClass` that I know for sure is actually an instance of one of its subclasses.

```
MinorClassA subclassedObj = new MinorClassA();
MajorClass obj = subclassedObj;

//------ More code -------------

if( subclassof(obj) == MinorClassA) //Something like this
```

How can I find out what is the subclass of that object? I do not have access to `subclassedObj`, only to `obj`.

Edit for clarification: I know how to check if `MinorClassA` is instance of `MajorClass`, but not the other way around.

Comment: `if (obj instanceof classname) ...`

Comment: *How can I find out what is the subclass of that object?* Program to the interface, why are you trying to determine the concrete type?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: "Program to the interface" should be seen as a good general rule, not dogma to follow in every situation. There can be legitimate reasons to check the execution-time type of an object.

Comment: `obj instanceof MinorClassA` ?

Comment: I dont think it is a duplicate, as that post is about checking if an object of class `Minor...` is an instance of `MajorClass`. My post is the other way around.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sure, that's why I asked in a comment; I have no idea what OP's use case is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want the [`instanceof` operator:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2)

> At run time, the result of the `instanceof` operator is true if the value of the *RelationalExpression* is not null and the reference could be cast to the *ReferenceType* without raising a `ClassCastException`. Otherwise the result is false.

So in your case:

```
if (obj instanceof MinorClassA) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: instance of does both compile time and run time check to perform parent and child class relationship analysis .    http://bytepadding.com/java/java-instanceof/

Comment: @KrazyGautam: Yes, but the compile-time checking isn't relevant in this question.

Answer (score 2):

Use instanceof to check if obj is an instance of the Class:

```
if (obj instanceof MinorClassA) {
   System.out.println("obj is an instance of MinorClassA");
} else if (obj instanceof MinorClassB) {
   System.out.println("obj is an instance of MinorClassB");
}
```